# Preserving Bash Colors When Shelling out Commands in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

Running `ls --color=auto` in bash shows directories as blue on my machine. Yet running `stdout (inshell "ls --color=auto" empty)` in Turtle loses all said color data. Is there a way to preserve coloring data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "auto" part means ls will only use colour when it knows that stdout is a "real" terminal. If you change to "always" then it will always use colour:

```
stdout (inshell "ls --color=always" empty)
```